# JSON.parse failing on valid Json. Have escaped control characters.If

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've escaped control characters and am feeding my validated JSON into JSON.parse and jQuery.parseJSON.  Both are giving the same result.

Getting error message `"Unexpected token $"`:

```js
$(function(){
    try{
        $.parseJSON('"\\\\\"$\\\\\"#,##0"');
    } catch (exception) {
        alert(exception.message);
    }    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks for checking out this issue.

Comment: The error seems to be in the pattern in `'{"id":"M","label":"Price","type":"number","pattern":"\\\\\"$\\\\\"#,##0"}'`.

Comment: There seems to be another issue after that 'unexpected number'. I can't find these for the life of me.

Comment: Interestingly, JSONLint declares the above string correct `JSON.parse` fails!

Comment: That's what I find so interesting. Anyone with eagle eyes that can spot the 'unexpected number' after deleting the value that Someone mentioned in the first comment?

Comment: And where is the JSON coming from ?

Comment: The json comes from JSON.stringify !!!

Comment: Then it should be ready to parse with `JSON.parse` without needing modifications from you ?

Comment: It should, as I said, JSONLint says it's okay yet JSON.parse fails, this is a very interesting issue.

Comment: Yeah it should be ready to parse, very frustrating. It was passed into a database, but with no modification or escape, excepting escaping control characters in JSON.stringify.

Comment: But there's no way `JSON.stringify` produces JSON that can't be parsed by `JSON.parse` so somewhere you're doing something to it that makes it fail.

Comment: Stringify is most probably producing a correct output. Intermediate operations (such as storing the string in the database, for example) must be messing with the quotes' escaping inside the string.

Comment: I will need to review my escaping rules. After I deleted the offending value, I still get an unexpected number error: http://jsfiddle.net/m8t89/24/

Comment: @Iftah - **http://jsfiddle.net/28kxxmvt/**, works just fine ?

Comment: @lftah Your example parse command works just fine, you just forgot a closing ")" at the end.

Comment: @adeneo oops you are right, I tried it in the console and that failed. Sorry!  I'll delete my first comment to avoid misleading others.

Comment: @Iftah - no problem! Generally `JSON.parse` will always parse what `JSON.stringify` has produced, so something is happened between the two that makes the JSON invalid, and stringifying will escape the special characters, I don't see why the string needs to be modified at all.

Comment: @robbintt It would make it easier if you narrowed down the problem yourself to the location specified in the error message instead of having us do it in that loooooooong string :) Hint: text editors show you column numbers, so finding column 853 (for example) should be easy...

Comment: That's a good idea in spirit, but effectively the only error message we are seeing is during JSON.parse, and that error reporting is very sparse unless you know a better way.

Comment: Just editing the given string so it works probably won't help much, you have to find what's causing the string to be invalid to begin with

Comment: @adeneo please put your note that my control character escapes are incorrect in an answer and I'll accept it. Good eye, mate.

Comment: I was just arguing that `stringify` was probably doing what it was supposed to, if you found an answer that doesn't match the given answer below, you can post the solution as an answer yourself. I honestly don't know what to answer ?

Comment: @adeneo My mistake that was someone else but they have since edited their answer removing the correct answer.

Comment: @robbintt, did my answer help you solve the problem?

Comment: @bgoldst unfortunately no, the correct issue is that I need to review and correct my manual escaping after the JSON.stringify. That should solve the issue with JSON.parse. Someone posted that idea in the comments and then deleted it.

Comment: @robbintt, I assure you that my answer is correct. The browser is removing backslashes when parsing the JavaScript string literal, which results in invalid JSON. That's why the (raw) JSON validates correctly, but when parsed from a JavaScript string literal it fails. Please take a look at my answer again.

Comment: I will review it tomorrow along with the other issue I see. Thanks for taking so much time to write it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original problem, why do you need to do JSONparse in the first place? You could have easily gotten the object you wanted by just doing

```
var o = { blah }
```

by manually removing the single quotes you have around the curly braces rather than doing

```
$.JSONparse('{blah}')
```

Is there any reason for evaluating the string first (ie var s = '{blah}' and then doing $.JSONparse(s)) which is what your original code was doing? There shouldn't be a case where this is necessary. Since you mentioned somewhere that the string was produced by JSON.stringify, there shouldn't be a scenario where you need to explicitly store it into a variable (ie copy and paste it and put quotes around it).

The main problem here is the string produced by JSON.stringify, which is properly escaped, has been 'evaluated' once when you manually put braces around it. So the key is to make sure the string doesn't get 'evaluated'

Even if you wanted to pass the stringified variable to database or anything, there is no need to explicitly use quotes. One could do

```
var s = JSON.stringify(obj);
db.save("myobj",s)
var newObj = JSON.parse(db.load("myobj"))
```

The string is stored verbatim without getting evaluated, so that when you retrieve it, you would have the exact same string.

Comment: This is an excellent point, which didn't cross my mind. JSON is valid JavaScript syntax (barring a single obscure and absurd incompatibility: http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset), and so there's never a need to hard-code JSON in a JavaScript string literal and then parse it out; you can just embed the JSON in lexical JavaScript and assign the resulting object literal to a variable! Nice addition @dlow.

Comment: This is perfect. I solved this by putting the json directly into brackets causing only one evaluation to occur. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

What's happening here is that there are two levels of backslash removal being applied to the string. The first is done by the browser's JavaScript engine when it parses the single-quoted string. In JavaScript, single-quoted strings and double-quoted strings are exactly equivalent (other than the fact that single-quotes *must* be backslash-escaped in single-quoted strings and double-quotes *must* be backslash-escaped in double-quoted strings); both types of strings take backslash escape codes such as `\\` for backslash, `\'` for single-quote (redundant but accepted in double-quoted strings), and `\"` for double-quote (redundant but accepted in single-quoted strings).

In your JavaScript single-quoted string literal you have several instances of this kind of thing, which are meant to be valid JSON double-quoted strings:

```
"\\\\\"$\\\\\"#,##0"
```

After the browser has parsed it, the string contains exactly the following characters (including the outer double-quotes, which are unremoved because they are contained in a single-quoted string):

```
"\\"$\\"#,##0"
```

You can see that each consecutive pair of backslashes became a single literal backslash, and the two cases of an odd backslash followed by a double-quote each became a literal double-quote.

*That* is the text that is being passed as an argument to `$.parseJSON`, which is when the second level of backslash removal occurs. During JSON parsing of the above text, the leading double-quote signifies the start of a JSON string literal, then the pair of backslashes is interpreted as a single literal backslash, and then the immediately following double-quote terminates the JSON string literal. The stuff that follows (dollar, backslash, backslash, etc.) is invalid JSON syntax.

The problem is that you've embedded valid JSON in a JavaScript single-quoted string literal, which, although it happens to be valid JavaScript syntax by fluke (it *wouldn't* have been if the JSON contained single-quotes, or if you'd tried using double-quotes to delimit the JavaScript string literal), no longer contains valid JSON after being parsed by the browser's JavaScript engine.

To solve the problem, you have to either manually escape the JSON content to be properly embedded in a JavaScript string literal, or load it independently of the JavaScript source, e.g. from a flat file.

Here's a demonstration of how to solve the problem using your latest example code:

```
$(function() {
    try {
        alert($.parseJSON('{"key":"\\\\\\\\\\"$\\\\\\\\\\"#,##0"}').key); // works
        alert($.parseJSON('{"key":"\\\\\"$\\\\\"#,##0"}').key); // doesn't work
    } catch (exception) {
        alert(exception.message);
    }    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/814uw638/2/

Since JavaScript has a simple escaping scheme (e.g. see http://blogs.learnnowonline.com/2012/07/19/escape-sequences-in-string-literals-using-javascript/), it's actually pretty easy to solve this problem in the general case. You just have to decide in advance how you're going to quote the string in JavaScript (single-quotes are a good idea, because strings in JSON are always double-quoted), and then when you prepare the JavaScript source, just add a backslash before every single-quote and every backslash in the embedded JSON. That should guarantee it will be perfectly valid, regardless of the exact JSON content (provided, of course, that it is valid JSON to begin with).

Comment: Sounds like a plausible answer, but if the issue is double escaping of JSON strings, I believe this is a duplicate of several other questions

Comment: This isn't right, I've already manually escaped control characters as stated in the question. JSON.parse also accepts a string type so the second half of the answer isn't right either. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: @robbintt - actually, parts of it makes sense, the JSON does lint as valid, and it is true that in certain circumstances the javascript parser removes the escaping, and strings must be double escaped to handle it, but that's if the string is written literally and parsed by the parser, which your string is in the above code example, but when coming from a DB it generally doesn't get parsed, and shouldn't need double escaping etc.

Comment: In this case the DB is performing no manipulation of the control character escaped, stringified javascript object, it's a raw text store.

Comment: @robbintt If `"$"#,##0` is the string contents you want, `JSON.parse('"\\"$\\"#,##0"')` would be needed. Every additional backslash you want in the output would required **four** backslashes in a JavaScript string literal. The point is that JSON strings cannot be inserted verbatim into JavaScript code.